# Which type can i use in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store a number (12,000) in mysql.This number is to be displayed on a webpage and as well be used in calculations.is there any data type that can be used to achieve this.Currently i am using an int data type and it can't showcase commas.i have tried other types but it isn't possible

Comment: Showing the format `12,000` is mostly a presentation thing, and typically is handled outside of MySQL.  What is querying your MySQL database?

Comment: Why do you want to store the number with comma?. Let the query writer and web developer to show the number using format function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **numeric data type** with comma however you can select numbers with predefined **[FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_format.asp)** function in MySql like this:

```
select Format(YOUR_FIELD_NAME,0)
```

Footnote: If you dont want to modify your SQL queries, there are many other solutions in coding languages even clien-side javascript formatting.